# Does anyone know how to reproduce an NVL() function in linq

Tags: linq, nvl

So I need to do a query where I need a bunch of NVL's but I need to do these in linq (if it helps the db backend is BD2 and we are using subsonic) I searched the web for "NVL linq" and didn't really find anything useful so I am asking here,

Thanks for your help...

Comment: can you give us an example of a query you need to do this in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the null coalescing operator `??`:

```
var abs = from row in table
          select new {a = row.a ?? "default", b = row.b};
```

The operator looks at the value on the left and if it is null then it uses the value on the right. So in the example if `row.a` is null, then `a` becomes `"default"`.

This assumes that `row.a` is a string.

Comment: And if `row.a` is `int`?
" ?? can't be applied to int and int"

Comment: @JonathanPeel I would expect that any DB query will return `int?` not plain `int`. If you are returning plain `int`, you can cast it to `int?`.

Comment: I can try that. I know you can't `as` something in an expression, but maybe I could `(int?)` it.

Comment: If you know it's an `int` why do you want to check if it's null?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know how I ended up doing this I didn't use the null coalesce operator... It was even simpler than that. Maybe I didn't explain my self clearly but what I needed to do was to say that if the value is null then means I want to include that result. Check it out.

```
 possibleVendors = (from vndMapping in db.COMPANIES_VND_MAPPINGS
                     join v in db.COMPANIES_CMP_COMPANIES on vndMapping.VENDOR_ID equals v.COMPANY_ID
                     where
                     !(from ex in db.COMPANIES_VND_MAPPINGS
                        where (ex.OEM_ID == oemId || ex.OEM_ID == null)
                        && (ex.MODEL_ID == modelId || ex.MODEL_ID == null)
                        && (ex.MODALITY_ID == modalityId || ex.MODALITY_ID == null)
                        && (ex.CLASS_ID == productTypeId || ex.CLASS_ID == null)
                        && ex.EXCLUDE.ToUpper().Equals("Y")
                        select ex.VENDOR_ID).Contains(vndMapping.VENDOR_ID)
                     && (vndMapping.OEM_ID == oemId || vndMapping.OEM_ID == null)
                     && (vndMapping.MODEL_ID == modelId || vndMapping.MODEL_ID == null)
                     && (vndMapping.MODALITY_ID == modalityId || vndMapping.MODALITY_ID == null)
                     && (vndMapping.CLASS_ID == productTypeId || vndMapping.CLASS_ID == null)
                     select new
                     {
                       vndMapping.VENDOR_ID,
                       v.COMPANY_NAME
                     }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.VENDOR_ID).ToDictionary(x => x.VENDOR_ID, x => x.COMPANY_NAME);
```

Now keep in mind - I had a few limitations in that I didn't design the business logic (obviously) or the database - Someone else might have a better way to do this if you had complete control of everything, this seems to work though.